# Call outside JavaScript function inside angularJS brackets

Tags: angularjs, scope

Is there a way to call an outside javascript function inside angularJS brackets, without having to use signals?

For example:

**HTML**

```
<td data-title="'PHONE'"> {{ formatPhone(p.phone) }} </td>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', [ 'ngTable' ]);

//my controller
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $http, NgTableParams) {

    //...

});

//my outside function
var formatPhone = function(p) {
    //...
};
```

Comment: You can't evaluate unless the function is attached to some scope

Comment: Why do you even want to do that ? What would that make any difference from attaching scope tot the function?

Comment: @Angular_10 to reuse code and avoid having equal functions on my code. But I solve that by calling this function from another function attached on the scope.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use a scope function, it needs to exists in the scope. You can just pass the function inside of the controller.

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $http, NgTableParams) {
     $scope.formatPhone = formatPhone
});

//my outside function
var formatPhone = function(p) {
    //...
};
```